# how to create a trigger in oracle which will restrict insertion and update queries on a table based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have account table as this--

```
create table account
(
acct_id int,
cust_id int,
cust_name varchar(20)  
)

insert into account values(1,20,'Mark');
insert into account values(2,23,'Tom');
insert into account values(3,24,'Jim');
```

I want to create a trigger which will ensure that no records can be inserted or update in account table having acct_id as 2 and cust_id as 23.

My code is --

```
create trigger tri_account
before insert or update
on account
for each row
begin
    IF (:new.acct_id == 2 and :new.cust_id == 23) THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No insertion with id 2 and 23.');
rollback;
    END IF; 
end;
```

so this trigger is created , but with compilation error.
now when I insert any record with acct_id as 2 and cust_id as 23,it doesent allow.
But I get an error saying 
**ORA-04098: trigger 'OPS$0924769.TRI_ACCOUNT' is invalid and failed re-validation**

I don't understand this.I also want to show a message that dis insertion is not possible.
please Help...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. The equality operator in Oracle is `=`, not `==`.
2. You cannot commit or rollback in a trigger.  You can throw an exception which causes the triggering statement to fail and to be rolled back (though the existing transaction will not necessarily be rolled back).
3. It does not appear that this trigger compiled successfully when you created it.  If you are using SQL*Plus, you can type `show errors` after creating a PL/SQL object to see the compilation errors.
4. You should never write code that depends on the caller being able to see the output from `DBMS_OUTPUT`.  Most applications will not so most applications would have no idea that the DML operation failed if your trigger simply tries to write to the `DBMS_OUTPUT` buffer.

Putting those items together, you can write something like

```
create trigger tri_account
before insert or update
on account
for each row
begin
    IF (:new.acct_id = 2 and :new.cust_id = 23) THEN 
        raise_application_error( -20001, 'No insertion with id 2 and 23.');
    END IF; 
end;
```

Comment: I am still getting this error, when I try to insert the same record--insert into account values(2,23,'JAMMm');  the error is ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-20001: No insertion with id 2 and 23. 
ORA-06512: at "OPS$0924769.TRI_ACCOUNT", line 3 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'OPS$0924769.TRI_ACCOUNT'

Comment: I have one more question How to use to_char function in the condition clause in the above code . What I have tried is...                     IF (:new.acct_id = 2 and (select to_char(:new.startdate, 'MONTH')) = 'JUNE') Its giving me compilation  error. please help.

Comment: @Ashishdmc4 - that's the error you'd expect.  A trigger can only prevent a row from being inserted by throwing an error.

Comment: @Ashishdmc4 - That seems like a separate question-- it would be better to ask that as a separate question rather than placing new questions in a comment.  That being said, you don't need a separate `SELECT`.  Just `if( :new.acct_id = 2 AND to_char(:new.startdate,'fmMONTH') = 'JUNE')`

Answer (score 3):

A trigger is more flexible, but you can also accomplish this through the use of a CHECK CONSTRAINT:

```
ALTER TABLE account ADD CONSTRAINT check_account CHECK ( acct_id != 2 OR cust_id != 23 )
ENABLE NONVALIDATE;
```

The NONVALIDATE clause will ensure that the check constraint does not attempt to validate existing data, though it will validate all future data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF (:new.acct_id = 2 and :new.cust_id = 23) THEN
```

must be `OR`, not `and`.

Comment: Actually no, the 2 ids are different: one is `acct_id` and the other is `cust_id`. The `IF (:new.acct_id = 2 and :new.cust_id = 23) THEN` is correct as it is.

Answer (score 0):

While using conditional checks you don't need to use colons (`:`). This will always cause errors.

Note: Exclude the colon only in cases where condition checking is performed.