# PL/SQL Row is added even when the trigger throws an exception

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

When and exception is raised in my trigger, the row is still added to the table.
Here's my trigger:

```sql
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER t_ships
BEFORE INSERT ON DOCKING
  FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    cweight SHIPS."cargo weight"%TYPE;
    cap PIERS.capacity%TYPE;
    EX_WEIGHT EXCEPTION;
    bad_date EXCEPTION;

  BEGIN

    SELECT s."cargo weight" into cweight from SHIPS s where s.SID = :NEW.SID;
    SELECT p.capacity into cap from PIERS p where p.PID = :NEW.PID;

    IF cweight>cap THEN
    RAISE ex_weight;
    ELSIF :NEW."arrival date">:NEW."departure date" THEN RAISE bad_date;
    END IF;

    UPDATE PIERS
    set "Total ships" = "Total ships" + 1
    WHERE PID = :NEW.PID;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN EX_WEIGHT THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Weight exceeds capacity');
        RETURN;
      WHEN bad_date THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Arrival date is after departure date');
        RETURN;

  END;
```

It prints the error details, but still adds the row. When I try to use the `EXIT` command it compiles with warnings and the trigger won't work. What can cause this?

Comment: You are swallowing the exception thus it's never signaled to the caller that an exception occurred. You need to `RAISE` the exception in order to make the caller see it. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS99960

Comment: see also this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654623/how-to-create-a-trigger-in-oracle-which-will-restrict-insertion-and-update-queri

Comment: Thank you both, the `RAISE` statement solved it.

Comment: For future reference DBMS_OUTPUT is a developer convenience but inappropriate for handling errors: too many client environments won't display the  messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
[...]
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN EX_WEIGHT THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Weight exceeds capacity');
        RAISE; -- Rethrow the exception
      WHEN bad_date THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Arrival date is after departure date');
        RAISE; -- Rethrow the exception

  END;
```